# SDL2 Thread not working inside class

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, pointers, sdl-2

I am trying to create a input handler using multi threading with the SDL2 Library; however, when I try to put a thread in a class it won't compile and gives me this error...

```
error: cannot convert 'inputHandlerClass::getInput' from type 'int (inputHandlerClass::)(void*)' to type 'SDL_ThreadFunction {aka int (*)(void*)}'
```

I'm pretty sure that its the way I am passing the function name (fn) to the SDL_CreateThread function.

This is the source.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL_thread.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include "..\include\gameClass.hpp"
#include "..\include\inputHandlerClass.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    inputHandlerClass inputHandler;
    inputHandler.startThread();
    std::cout << "hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

This is the inputHandlerClass.hpp

```
#include <SDL_thread.h>
#include <iostream>

class inputHandlerClass{
    private:
        SDL_Thread *thread;
        int threadReturnValue;
    public:
        inputHandlerClass();
        int getInput(void *ptr);
        void startThread();
};

//Default Constructor
inputHandlerClass::inputHandlerClass(){
    this->thread = SDL_CreateThread(getInput, "inputThread", this);
}

int inputHandlerClass::getInput(void *ptr){
    int cnt;
    for(cnt= 0; cnt < 10; ++cnt){
        std::cout << "counter: " << cnt << std::endl;
        SDL_Delay(50);
    }
    return cnt;
}

void inputHandlerClass::startThread(){
    SDL_WaitThread(this->thread, &this->threadReturnValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`SDL_CreateThread` expects a pointer to a regular function with `int(void *ptr)` signature as first parameter, however you are providing a non-static member function (not even a pointer because member functions aren't getting implicitly converted to a pointer). You should redeclare `getInput` as static. `this` pointer will be available as `ptr`.

Comment: I tried re-declaring as a static member function, but now I get the following error. error: cannot declare member function 'static int inputHandlerClass::getInput(void*)' to have static linkage [-fpermissive]

Comment: Maybe you've changed function definition instead of declaration?

Comment: I found a fix. I was using the gnu compiler and when I gave the compiler the -fpermissive flag it ignored the error, and compiled successfully.

Comment: You should've fix error instead of using `-fpermissive`. Typically code should be compiled without any warnings with `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic` while the use of `-fpermissive` is strictly prohibited.

Comment: You're right about not leaning on a temporary fix, but now I got it to work with out the warning. I just needed to take out the static from the definition, but leave it in the class declaration.